# Conditional space in PS1

Tags: git, bash, prompt, ps1

I'm basically trying to create a PS1 that has this output:

```
$ ~/Projects/Blah (master):
```

However, if the folder I'm in is not a Git repository, I want it to look like this instead:

```
$ ~/Projects/Blah:
```

This is my current PS1:

```
export PS1="$ \w \$(__git_ps1): "
```

It gives me the output I want for when I'm in a Git repo, but when I'm in a folder that is not in a Git repo, the output looks like this:

```
$ ~/Projects/Blah :
```

I don't really want that space there if it isn't a Git repo.

Is there some way I can specify this in my PS1?

Comment: Do you control the output from `__git_ps1` just move the space over there .

Comment: I have `__git_ps1` equal to `"git branch 2>/dev/null | grep '*' | sed 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'"`. I tried inserting spaces in various places there, but it didn't seem to work. I'm not too familiar with what's going on with that line, I believe I copied it from somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using this [`.git-prompt.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh) file. Steps to get this to work:

1. Create a file called `.git-prompt.sh` in your home directory (`~/.git-prompt.sh`) and copy the code from the link above into it.
2. In your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` file, add this line: `source ~/.git-prompt.sh`
3. Change your PS1 to this: `PS1='\n$ \w$(__git_ps1 " (%s)"): '`

Answer (score 4):

It's usually much simpler to build your prompt up piece-by-piece using `PROMPT_COMMAND`, which is code executed just before each prompt is displayed. (`PS1` doesn't need to be exported, by the way.)

```
build_prompt () {
    PS1="$ \w"
    git_info=$(__git_ps1)
    if [[ $git_info ]]; then
        PS1+=" $git_info"
    fi
    PS1+=": "
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=build_prompt
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> export PS1="$ \w \$(__git_ps1): "
> ```
>
> I have __git_ps1 equal to `git branch 2>/dev/null | grep '*' | sed 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'`.

Change your `__git_ps1` to:

```
git branch 2>/dev/null | grep '*' | sed 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
```

Note the extra white-space in the `sed` replacement before `(\1)`.

*Edit1*: Simplified `__git_ps1` by @andlrc with one command less:

```
__git_ps1() { git branch 2>/dev/null | sed -n 's/\* \(.*\)/ (\1)/p'; }
```

Comment: No need for grep `... | sed -n 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/p'`

Comment: @andlrc, I'm not an expert in advanced `sed`. Your command prints everything, and the current branch twice. I think you need the `d` after the `s///p`.

Comment: You forgot to set the `-n` flag?

Comment: @andlrc, Yes, I did. Tested and added to the answer.

Comment: `-n` will disable print by default, and p after the substitution (`s///`) will print that line if the substitution is successful. You can also, as you pointed out, delete every line and print the wanted line twice: `... | sed 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/p;d'`.

Answer (score 0):

Prepare the `git_ps1` like this:

```
git_ps1=$(git branch 2>/dev/null | grep '*')
git_ps1="${git_ps1:+ (${git_ps1/#\* /}) }"
##                  ^space             ^space
## Change the spaces if you like it other ways.
```

`git_ps1` will be like `(master)`, with spaces at both ends; and a complete empty string when `git_ps1` is not set (for non-git dir) . Now you can just use the `$git_ps1` variable to insert it anywhere you like.

Explanation:

```
git_ps1="${git_ps1:+ (${git_ps1/#\* /}) }"
```

is a **conditional variable assignment**.

1. if `git_ps1` is set then it will be equal to `(${git_ps1/#\* /})`, otherwise it will remain empty.
2. `${git_ps1/#\* /}` cuts the `*` and space from the beginning of `$git_ps1`

---

**Example Usage:**

```
__git_ps1(){
    git_ps1=$(git branch 2>/dev/null | grep '*')
    git_ps1="${git_ps1:+ (${git_ps1/#\* /})}"
    echo "$git_ps1"
}
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[00m\]\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]$(__git_ps1) \[\033[1;32m\]>\[\033[00m\]\[\033[1;32m\]>\[\033[00m\]\[\033[1;32m\]>\[\033[00m\] '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

This gives me a prompt like this one:
[image]